# How do I get the values I want out of this excel table?

Tags: excel

The purpose of this table is to find the correct current carrying capacity and the cross-section of a cable.

The table has two axes. Installation method (1-4) and cross-section.

I'm trying to create a program in which I enter the minimum current capacity and Installation method and the program outputs the minimum cross section and current capacity.

[Here's a part of the table:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/weTD0.png)

Eksample:
I enter the values min. 11A and installation method nr. 1.
The output is 13.5A and 1.5mm^2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way of doing it

For Current

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$D$5,G2,MATCH(TRUE,(F2<=INDEX($B$2:$D$5,G2,0)),0)),"Insufficient capacity")
```

For Cross-section

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$D$1,MATCH(TRUE,(F2<=INDEX($B$2:$D$5,G2,0)),0)),"Insufficient capacity")
```

both put in as array formulas using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]